# Separate subdomain for each client

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

let's say I have a table User and table Products:

```
Name        Company
John Doe       1
Alex Doe       2
Michael Doe    1

ProductName Company  
Tea            1
Coffee         1

CompanyId   CompanyName
   1         Comapny1  
   2         Company2
```

Now I want to have a separate login for companies at Company.MyDomain.Com and Company2.MyDomain.Com, etc.

Clients register subdomains by themselves.   This will allow me to show separate list of products for each subdomain. What is the best way to do this?  Should I use routing? Or just use javascript to replace domain with a fake domain name? (I'm currently using simplemembership)

Comment: What do you think of my response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can set the "appdomain" with `Roles.ApplicationName`. If you set: `Roles.ApplicationName = "Company"`, then the roleprovider working with subset of roles from Application=Company. Similarly, you can set `Roles.ApplicationName = "Company2"`.
2. Unfortunately, Roles is [static object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security.Roles.aspx), Roles.ApplicationName is
   [static property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.applicationname.aspx).

   "Your entire ASP.NET MVC application runs within an AppDomain, that
   is the application plus all requests being served for all users,
   everything!!

   When you create a static variable, a single instance is declared and
   made available to the entire AppDomain, every request from every
   user will see the same value."

   [problem with static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556540/problem-with-static-variable)

   So, you must lock the thread while run [authorize](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs), or [you can
   write your own role provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872202/custom-membership-and-role-provider-in-asp-net-mvc-4).
3. You can make [routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278668/is-it-possible-to-make-an-asp-net-mvc-route-based-on-a-subdomain) based [subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436268/mvc-3-subdomain-routing).